# How to vertically center text in DIV but float horizontally?

Tags: css

Envision two rectangular DIVs side by side.  Let's say the left one has a red background color and the right one has a blue background color.  For argument's sake, let's say that each is 250px wide.  The height changes according to the content within, but is typically 100px to 300px tall.

I want to display a single character, an equals sign that sits precisely in the center - ie. is vertically centered and sits 50% on the red DIV and 50% on the blue DIV.

To effect a solution, I did this:

- Set the red DIV to width = `col-4`
- Added a center DIV, also red, with a width = `col-1`
- Set the blue DIV to width = `col-5`

The center DIV contains the equals sign, which is 50px x 50px in size and has a circle around it.

To vertically center, I set the center column to have `display: flex` and `align-items: center`.  This works well.

But, try as I might, I could not shift the character over no matter what I tried.  I suspect this might be because I'm using `flex` in the parent DIV.

Any ideas how to effect a workable solution?

Comment: Considering the class names you mention, are you using bootstrap grid?

Comment: Please don't explain what you have tried, instead show us the code. Which will give us an proper idea for where to help you

Comment: What do you mean by _shift the character over_? Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/32nzjw5s/

Comment: Or this ? https://jsfiddle.net/wh6L75p4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following css to the center div:

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
flex-direction: column;
text-align: center;
```

what you are doing here is making the flex-direction vertical then you are making the text vertically center after that text-align: center

Comment: Your use of `flex-direction: column` is interesting and something I was not aware of.  Unfortunately the rest of your CSS code isn't applicable to me because I need to shift the equals sign (the child of the DIV) over to the right so that it appears to sit on top of the divider between the red & blue DIVs.  How would one do that?

Comment: please provide the code so that we can better assist you.

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if the "col-number" you're using is something to do with bootstrap.  I think you're overcomplicating things here.

If the central div has a width of 50px, then all you need to do is set the margins to -25px and make sure the z-index is higher than the div after it in the page.

I tried the following code and it seemed to do what you want.

```
<div style="display:flex; align-items:center;">
  <div style="background:#f00; font-size:300px"> A </div>
  <div style="width:50px; margin:-25px; z-index:1; font-size:100px">=</div>
  <div style="background:#00f; font-size:500px"> B </div>
</div>
```

You'll probably want that css kept separate from the markup. If the central element's an image, you don't need to wrap it in a div.  Just apply the css to the image.

Comment: To clarify, just try adding `margin:-25px; z-index:1;` to the style of your central div.

Answer (score 1):

Much thanks to both Andrew Paul and Ankur Choudhury.  I used a combination of your responses to effect a working solution.

**Layout Code**

```
<div className={`col-1 ${cn.CenterColumn}`}>
    <div className={cn.Equal}>
        =
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS Code**

```
CenterColumn: css({
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    border: '0.063em solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)',
    borderLeft: 'none',
    backgroundColor: '#ececec',
    zIndex: 1
}),

Equal: css({
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    width: '50px',
    height: '50px',
    borderRadius: '50px',
    fontSize: '50px',
    color: '#fff',
    lineHeight: '50px',
    textAlign: 'center',
    marginRight: '-78px'
}),
```

*Note: The CSS code above is actually inside a `styles.ts` file in my React component.*